# Get final total price at checkout

Tags: magento2, shipping, shopping-cart-price-rules, checkout-page

At checkout, I would like to have the checkout total price (display in the right corner in the order summary box) in order to display a message under the 'Order Total' according to his value (and according to the payment method selected). And I want to send the 'Order Total' information to my server too.

To send the Order Total, I use an observer (predispatchCheckout) and call the quote->getGrandTotal but the shipping cost is not included.

And for the displaying message, I create a component in checkout_index_index.html :

```
<item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="myapp_total" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MyApp_MyApp/js/view/checkout/summary/myapp_total</item>
            </item>
          </item>
        </item>
      </item>
    </item>
  </item>
</item>
```

And use the different classes to get the information:

```
[
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals',
        'mage/url',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
    ],
```

But the total price is not the final one. There is no shipping cost included. And when I try to have it on the payment method selection, I don't have the right price the first time but when I change the payment method, this time, the shipping cost is here.

How can I manage it?

Maybe you have another idea to have the checkout total and display a message according to it.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the grand total:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
], function ($, $t, $checkoutData, $quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (defaultView) {
        return defaultView.extend({
            {inYourCustomMethod}: function (data, event) {
                 let getGrandTotal = parseFloat($quote.totals()['grand_total']);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

To get the order total (subtotal + shipping + tax) as the Order Total shows in the Order Summary, you should use `Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals` JavaScript component to get `totals.getSegment('grand_total')` as [vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/estimation.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.6/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/estimation.js#L33) did:

```
define(['Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'], function (totals) { ... }
```

```
/**
 * @return {Number}
 */
getGrandTotal: function () {
    if (totals.totals()) {
        return parseFloat(totals.getSegment('grand_total').value);
    }

    return 0;
},
```